# How do I point my DNS to an AWS ElasticBeanstalk Instance?

Tags: ssl, networking, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-certificate-manager

I've taken the following steps:

-Created an ElasticBeanstalk instance with URL `my-instance.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`

-Bought a Domain `my-domain.com` from Godaddy

-Got a SSL cert via AWS Certificate Manager for `my-domain.com`

-Added a CNAME record `my-instance.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` pointing to `my-domain.com` in GoDaddy

I've waited about 12 hours for the changes to take effect, but visiting `http://my-domain.com` and `https://my-domain.com` are both giving me the error
"This site can’t be reached: my-domain.com’s server IP address could not be found."

Am I missing any steps here?

Comment: Verify if your beanstalk DNS can be accessed publicly.

Comment: @RaulBarreto Yes, it can.

Comment: Have you used `Route 53` service of aws to map your domain to aws instance?

Comment: @JijoCleetus No I read that Simply pointing elasticbeanstalk's URL to the DNS should be sufficient

Comment: Does your website work if you just use EB domain: my-instance.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com ?

Comment: @Marcin Yep, just no https://

Comment: Where did you install the ACM cert? Its not explained in your question. On your load balancer?

Comment: Also you CNAMe should be oposit. Instead of " CNAME record my-instance.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com pointing to my-domain.com", it should be "Added a CNAME record my-domain.com pointing to my my-instance.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I abandoned this approach and have successfully set up SSL using and DNS pointing via AWS Route 53. AWS made it very easy.